# referencing shell script path to python

Tags: python, shell, pandas, path, substitution

Hi I'm trying to reference a shell variable path from shell script to python

```
test.ksh
path1=/usr/bin/usr1/dev/data

  test.py
        df = pd.read_csv('%path1/testdataset1.dat')
```

I expect the last statement to resolve to

```
df = pd.read_csv('/usr/bin/usr1/dev/data/testdataset1.dat')
```

`%path1` is not working. I'm using python 2.6

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

- Access the environment variable within your Python script:

  ```
  import os

  path1 = os.environ.get('path1')
  if path1 is not None:
      df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path1, 'testdataset1.dat'))
  ```

  `os.environ` is a dictionary containing the process' environment variables as passed from the parent. Ensure that you export the required variables in your shell script, i.e.:

  ```
  export path1=/usr/bin/usr1/dev/data
  ```
- Pass `path1` as a command line argument to your Python script:

  ```
  import os, sys

  path1 = sys.argv[1]
  df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path1, 'testdataset1.dat'))
  ```

  Your shell script would invoke Python like this:

  ```
  path1=/usr/bin/usr1/dev/data
  python your_script.py $path1
  ```

Comment: Already changing that whilst you are commenting :) Anyway, it still depends on the components of `path1` using the appropriate path separator for the OS in question.

Comment: It won't matter to Python, it can deal with whatever paths you put in. You might also want to use `os.path.expanduser()`.